# Sefer Aftarta: does it need to contain them all?

Tags: haftarah, eis-laasos

In [Gittin 60a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin%2060a:4-6), the Talmud gives permission to write a *sefer aftarta*, a scroll containing just the haftarot for the year (and not full *sifrei nakh*). The reason given is עת לעשות לה׳ הפרו תורתך.

> וְרַבָּה וְרַב יוֹסֵף דְּאָמְרִי תַּרְוַיְיהוּ הַאי סֵפֶר אַפְטָרָתָא אָסוּר לְמִקְרֵי בֵּיהּ בְּשַׁבָּת מַאי טַעְמָא דְּלֹא נִיתַּן לִיכָּתֵב מָר בַּר רַב אָשֵׁי אָמַר לְטַלְטוֹלֵי נָמֵי אָסוּר מַאי טַעְמָא דְּהָא לָא חֲזֵי לְמִיקְרֵי בֵּיהּ וְלָא הִיא שְׁרֵי לְטַלְטוֹלֵי וּשְׁרֵי לְמִיקְרֵי בֵּיהּ דְּרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן וְרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן לָקִישׁ מְעַיְּינִי בְּסִפְרָא דְאַגַּדְתָּא בְּשַׁבְּתָא וְהָא לֹא נִיתַּן לִיכָּתֵב אֶלָּא כֵּיוָן דְּלָא אֶפְשָׁר עֵת לַעֲשׂוֹת לַיהוה הֵפֵרוּ תּוֹרָתֶךָ הָכָא נָמֵי כֵּיוָן דְּלָא אֶפְשָׁר עֵת לַעֲשׂוֹת לַיהוה הֵפֵרוּ תּוֹרָתֶךָ
>
> And Rabba and Rav Yosef both say: It is prohibited to publicly read the haftara, the portion from the Prophets that is read after the weekly Torah portion, on Shabbat, from a scroll containing only the haftarot. What is the reason for this? It is because this type of scroll may not be written, as the words of the Prophets must also be written as complete books ... But that is not so; rather, it is permitted to handle such a scroll and it is permitted to read from it ... in the case of a haftara scroll, [since it is not always possible to write complete books of the Bible, due to the expense,] it is permitted to apply the reasoning of “It is time to act for the Lord; they have nullified your Torah.”

Every *sefer aftarta* (admittedly very few) I've seen contains all the haftarot of the year. According to those opinions that prefer a *sefer aftarta* over a printed text, is this strictly necessary? Is there a difference between reading out of a *sefer aftarta* that contains all of the haftarot and any *klaf* written properly that contains the haftarah for that Shabbat? To reduce rolling around holidays, could you make a scroll with just the holiday haftarot and have another one for just the usual Shabbatot? If your synagogue has no *sefer aftarta*, but you want to read a given haftarah out of a scroll, could you write/commission just that haftarah on a *klaf* (because the whole thing is too expensive/takes too long)?

Comment: I've always assumed you could indeed write them individually. The only argument I can imagine against that is some special rabbinic enactment איידי דזוטרי מירכס but I know of no evidence for that. Curious that I've never seen holidays separately; that's a clever idea.

Comment: How do you even define "all" of the haftaros?  What about the ones for Matos - Vayeilech that exist in principle but always get overridden?

Answer (score 2):

> According to those opinions that prefer a sefer aftarta over a printed text, is this strictly necessary?

Certainly there have been *some* that have taken up that position, consider the following:

The Pisqei Rid (Gittin 60a) wrote:

> כיון דלא אפשר עת לעשות לה' הפרו תורתך שאין כל צבור וצבור יכולין ליכתוב
> כל הנביאים הילכך מותר ללקט כל ההפטרות ולכתבן בספר א'
>
> Since it isn't possible, [they declared] "It is time to act for the
> Lord; they have nullified your Torah", for not every congregation is
> able to write all of the Prophets, accordingly they permitted that **all
> of the Haftoroth be written and collated into one *sefer*.**

This seems to strongly imply that a ספר אפטרתא would need to include **all** of the Haftoroth.

It is also instructive to look at how communities that historically have retained the practice do so. Tefillah keMinhag Q"Q Ashkenazim (a practical siddur put out by Makhon Moresheth Ashkenaz, an organization dedicated to preserving Yekkish custom, under R. Binyomin Homburger), p. 100 prescribes that:

> לאחר שגמרו את גלילת ספר תורה מפטירין בנביאים מענין הפרשה את ההפטרה
> קורא העולה לתורה בעצמו מתוך ספר אפטרתא היינו אוסף של פרשיות נביאים
> השייכות לשבתות השנה והמועדים כתוב בדיו על גבי קלף האזכרות שבו נכתבו
> לשם קדושה ויש בו ניקוד וטעמים קבועים לו שני עמודים בשני צדיו ונגלל
> כספר תורה הוא עטוף במעיל וכרוך במפה ווימפל' כספר תורה מניחים את הספר
> בארון מיוחד לתשמישי מצוה ולא בארון הקודש א
>
> After gelilath ha-Torah is complete, we are maftir with the Prophets
> from a topic within the parashah with the Haftorah. The oleh to the
> Torah reads it himself from a Sefer Aftartha which collates the
> parshiyoth of the the Prophets that appertain to the Sabbaths of the
> year and the holidays. It is written with ink on qelaf and the holy
> names are written with intent of sanctification (l’shem qedushah), it
> is also written with niqud and te'amim, it is set with two columns on
> two sides and it is rolled like a Sefer Torah. It is enveloped with a
> covering and is wrapped with a wimpel sash like a Sefer Torah and the
> sefer is set to rest within an Aron designated for implements of
> miswah and not in the Aron ha-Qodesh.

It seems then that at least in Ashkenaz (i.e. Yekkish communities), the practice of reading from a Sefer Aftartha was not and is not done from loose, individual parshiyoth.

Rabbi Daniel Langer writes about his interpretation of the Ritva as follows ([Nehorai, pp. 669-670](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51593&hilite=d929c76f-7412-4b49-a2cc-248b9d769a89&st=%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%90&pgnum=683)):

> ובריטב"א כתב וז"ל, מ"ט דלא ניתנו ליכתב, והרי הוא כקורא דברים שבכתב על
> פה [ר"ל כיון שאין עליו תורת ספר, הרי הוא קורא דשב"כ שלא מן הספר ואסור]
> ואסיקנא דשרי למיקרי ביה ולטלטולי דהא ר"י ור"ל מעייני בספרא דאגדתא
> בשבתא משום עת לעשות לה' חפרו תורתך, עכ"ד. ומדבריו משמע דנידון אחד הוא,
> כיון שלא ניתן ליכתב הלכך גם הקריאה אסורה משום דברים שבכתב אא"ר לע"פ, ‏
> והגמ' מתרצת דניתן ליכתב וממילא אין בו איסור דשב"כ בע"פ. צ"ב נהי דהותרה
> הכתיבה, משום עת לעשות, אבל במה הותרה הקריאה הרי מ"מ אין על כתיבה כזו
> תורת ספר ובמה הותרה איסור הקריאה בע"פ שלא מן הספר… והנראה מבואר בדעת
> הריטב"א, שענין עת לעשות לה' בכאן אינו היתר על איסור כתיבת חלק של ספר
> בלא ספר שלם. אלא, קבעו חז"ל תורת ספר על ספרא דאפטרתא, שדיבורים אלו
> דהפטרות כל השנה בכללותן קובעים דבר שלם לעצמן, וכיון שזוהי הצורה השלימה
> של דיבורים אלו הלכך הוי ספרא דאפטרתא ספר שלם, וחייל עליה דין כתבי
> הקודש וקדושתן. ואשר ממילא יוצא מזה דשוב אין איסור דשב"כ בע"פ, דאדרבא
> הרי קורא מספר כשר... שבאמת קבעו חז"ל שספרא דאפטרתא בכללותו יש לו
> שלימות של ספר,ושפיר חייל עליה שם כתבי קודש, וצריך לכתבו דוקא בדיני
> כתיבת כתבי קודש...
>
> And the Ritva z”l wrote, “why wasn’t it fit to be written? For it is
> like he is reciting Written Scriptures by heart [which is to say that
> it isn’t being recited *b’torath sefer* accordingly he isn’t reciting
> Written Scripture from a *sefer*] so they answered that it is
> permitted to recite from them and to carry them for R. Yohanan and R.
> Simeon b. Laqish used to look through a book of Aggada on the Sabbath
> on the basis of ‘It is time to act for the Lord, they have nullified
> your Torah’.” And from his words it appears that it is one matter,
> since it initially wasn’t fit to be written it also was accordingly
> forbidden to be recited from since Written Scripture should not be
> recited by heart, and the Gemara conclusory answers that it was indeed
> fit to be written and evidently a prohibition of reciting Written
> Scriptures by heart would be inapplicable.  This requires some
> explanation, for the grounds on which the writing was permitted was
> “it is a time to act” but on what basis was reciting permitted? For in
> any event, such a writing wouldn’t be b’torath sefer and so on what
> basis would the prohibition of reading by heart from a portion of a
> sefer that is not complete, be permitted?... and so it appears that
> according to the Ritva that the matter of “it is a time to act” is not
> a license that permits writing a portion of a sefer that is not
> complete. Rather, Hazal designated the Sefer d’Aftartha as being
> b’torath sefer, since they collate the matter of the Haftoroth of the
> entire year within it it is thus a complete sefer (*sefer shalem*)
> unto itself, and since this is the complete form of this matter the
> Sefer d’Aftartha is considered a therefore a complete sefer, upon
> which devolves the ruling of kithvei qodesh (Holy Scriptures) and the
> sanctity that appertains. And evidently emerges from this that no
> prohibition of reciting Written Scriptures by heart apply, on the
> contrary – it is one is reading from a proper sefer (*sefer kasher*)…
> for in truth, Hazal designated that the Sefer d’Aftartha is altogether
> a complete sefer, and it is well that a *shem kithvei qodesh*
> (designation as a Scripture) devolves upon it, and it ought be written
> precisely with according to the rules appertaining to *kithvei qodesh*
> (Holy Scriptures).

In brief, according to R. Langer‘s reading of the Ritva, a Sefer d’Aftartha is a work designated by Hazal that collates all of the Haftoroth, and as a *sefer shalem* (comprehensive or complete work) unto itself, it achieves the sanctity and status of other *kithvei qodesh* that would be proper to read from. One would be hard-pressed to explain how an individually written and read Haftorah could qualify as such, in this view.

The Arukh ha-Shulhan ([OH 284:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%93)) states:

> אמרינן בגיטין (ס'.): דמן הדין היה אסור למקרי בספרא דאפטרתא. כלומר שהיו
> כותבין כל ההפטרות בקלף בכרך אחד - ואסור לקרות כשאין נביא שלם, כמו בספר
> תורה שאין לקרות כשאין הספר תורה שלימה, אך התירו משום 'עת לעשות לד'
> וגו' '. כלומר כיון דלא אפשר לכל ציבור וציבור לכתוב נביאים שלם, ולכן
> התירו בכתיבת ההפטרות בלבד... והרי עלינו לעשות כמו שעשו חכמי הש"ס
>
> They taught in Gittin (60a) that according to the letter of the law it
> was forbidden to recite from a Sifra d’Aftartha. Which is to say they
> would write therein all of the Haftaroth on qelaf in one volume – and
> it was forbidden to read therefrom because it was not a complete [book
> of the] Prophets, similar to a Sefer Torah inasmuch as we do not read
> therefrom if the Sefer Torah is incomplete, so they permitted on the
> basis of “it is a time to do for the Lord” etc. Which is to say since
> it was not possible for each and every congregation to write complete
> [books of the] Prophets, accordingly they permitted the writing of the
> Haftaroth alone… and it is incumbent upon us to do as the Sages of the
> Talmud did.

This seems to imply that according to R. Yehiel Mikhel Epstein, Hazal understood the term Sifra d'Aftartha to refer to a work containing all of the Haftoroth bound together in one volume and written on qelaf, and that once they permitted that such be used it is incumbent upon us to do the same.

Comment: Thank you. If this is the case, that a sefer aftarta is a "thing" that has shem sefer, why don't we see any prescription as to how to write a Sefer Aftarta (order of haftarot, which haftarot to include, etc)?

Comment: You present this as if there is only one side. There are other approaches to why it's ok to read "from memory" in this case.

Comment: No problem. It wasn't my intention to present this in a one sided way. I'd be glad to hear of other perspectives *within* your requested framework ("those opinions that prefer a sefer aftarta over a printed text"). As for which haftaroth and their order, that is an interesting question though I don't think it inherently detracts from this view point. Perhaps according to this view it isn't inherently a static text and as long as it covers all of the appropriate times for a reading with a selection, its function is covered, and thus the *shem sefer* qua *sefer shalem* is retained.Just a thought

Comment: Your inference from Pisqei Rid is, in my opinion, a little weak. Clearly Rav Langer’s chiddush would rule out a singular haftarah scroll, but I’m not convinced that that’s the only way to read Ritva.

Comment: @JoelK the Pisqei Rid seems to define the scope. I don't see how he could be interpreted as advancing something *less* than what he states is what Hazal endorsed as permitted. As for the interpretation of the Ritva, that is certainly true - and other poseqim certainly gather other inferences from his articulated position.